# JavaScript node / module without using the variable name

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Apologies for the title but I wasn't sure how to phrase this.

In a normal module you have the following format:

```
var SomeClass = function() { 
...
};
module.exports = SomeClass;
```

You can shorthand that to:

```
module.exports = function() { 
...
};
```

There is however a problem with the second notation if you need to use the 'class' name inside itself ( to instantiate a new object of itself for example). Using the 1st example this would be easy ...

```
var SomeClass = function() { 
...
function doSomething() {
   var x = new SomeClass();
}
...
};
module.exports = SomeClass;
```

Is this possible using the 2nd notation? I know I can't use 'this' as that is an instance variable, I also can't use any form of the module.

```
module.exports = function() { 
...
function doSomething() {
   var x = new ??????
}
...
};
```

I'm asking purely from an aesthetic and a uniformity point of view.

Any Help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but it really isn't clear what you're asking or what your comment about `this` means.  You are free to give a function a name before assigning to `module.exports` or not - that is entirely your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this in the form that you describe. Theoretically, to you in that scope, there is no difference between `SomeClass` and `module.exports`: both are variables and you give them both the same value.

Therefor, if you wanted, you could have something like this (though it looks odd):

```
module.exports = function() { 
// ...
function doSomething() {
   var x = new module.exports();
}
// ...
};
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. That works perfectly, thanks.